# GWT gwt-maven-plugin wrong sourcelevel warning in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gwt

Using following config in pom

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${gwt.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            <style>${gwtcompiler.style}</style>
            <optimizationLevel>${gwtcompiler.optimizationLevel}</optimizationLevel>
            <sourceLevel>auto</sourceLevel>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
            <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <extraJvmArgs>
        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/projectlombok/lombok/${lombok.version}/lombok-${lombok.version}.jar=ECJ
        --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
    </extraJvmArgs>
    <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
    <sourceLevel>auto</sourceLevel>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

```
<sourceLevel>auto</sourceLevel>
```

following false warning

[image]

is generating

Warning comes from
generated Project Settings
Facets

[image]

did even try with 1.11 or 1.8

Using latest GWT

~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-21.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java

Any assistance or insights you can provide would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for taking the time to read. Your expertise is invaluable, and I welcome any suggestions or solutions you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer on :

> rob5n (Rob Newton) If you are using the  section to
> configure the compiler for java 1.8, use
> <maven.compiler.source>1.8</...> and <maven.compiler.target>1.8</...>
> . Or for java 11, use <maven.compiler.release>11</...>. AND remove the
> tags in the  section such as
> <maven.compiler.source>, otherwise these will overwrite your
> properties.

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply - your example above is trying and failing to use a Java 6 feature (diamond generics), but GWT 2.9+ supports Java 11 features. The next release, GWT 2.12 will add Java 17 features.

Comment: It wasn't GWT ... Our project has 7 pom files, causing confusion with target and Maven plugin. Managed to fix it miraculously (unknown magic), and all warnings disappeared.